# Android ContextMenu how set TextColor and bg color?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I need to change the color of the text in a ContextMenu. I try to use @style, but doesn't work. I cheked the post: [Setting Application theme textColor to white causes Context Menu item text to be white (invisible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749677/setting-application-theme-textcolor-to-white-causes-context-menu-item-text-to-be), cause de doubt is simillar, but no dont works too. Someone can help me or tell me that is not possible change the color?

Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <style name= "Theme.Blundell.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_light</item>
     <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Widget.TextView.Black</item>
   </style>

   <style name="Widget.TextView.Black" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
       <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
   </style>
```